# Contar quantidade de "buracos" nas letras de um texto

Tags: python, algoritmo

Preciso escrever um programa em Python que conte a quantidade de "buracos" numa string. Imagine, por exemplo, que as letras "A", "D", "O", "P", "R" possuem apenas um buraco. Da mesma forma, a letra "B" possui dois buracos. Já as letras "C", "E", "F", "K" não possuem buracos. O programa deve considerar que o número de buracos em um texto é igual ao número total de buracos nas letras do texto. O usuário deve fornecer na entrada duas informações, em duas linhas: A primeira linha contém um inteiro simples T <= 40 que indica o número de casos de testes. Depois, seguem-se T casos de teste. Cada linha do caso de teste contém um texto não vazio composto somente de caracteres maiúsculos do alfabeto inglês. O tamanho de cada texto é menor que 100. Não existem espaços na entrada.Para cada caso de teste, a saída consiste de uma linha contendo o número de buracos encontrado no caso de teste. Se as entradas forem:

```
3
LARANJA
UVA
PERA
```

A saída seria:

```
4
1
3
```

Ainda não tentei nenhum código que fosse promissor. Preciso de uma dica.

Comment: Já conseguiu pensar em como começar a desenvolver? Pelo menos os passos iniciais?

Comment: @DiegoF Tem razão, não tinha visto. Mas, se eu fosse ele, removeria tanto do início da pergunta quanto da tag, já que é uma pergunta sobre algoritmo. Seria um começo para fazer a pergunta ser melhor recebida.

Comment: Pensei em atribuir um valor a cada letra relevante, ou seja, aquelas que possuem "buracos", de acordo com o número de "buracos" que ela tem. A string fornecida seria lida pelo programa, passando por cada letra e contabilizando os valores de cada uma e somando no final. Minha dificuldade está em administrar as funções da maneira correta.

Comment: @DiegoF Nesse tipo de pergunta, na qual o AP quer um "norte" (como estava escrito na pergunta original), marcada com a tag algoritmo, eu não vejo como a linguagem é relevante. Acaba restringindo e diminuindo a possiblidade de ele encontrar uma resposta. Quem tem a tag Python escondida não vê essa pergunta, mesmo sendo capaz de responder.

Comment: Não é que eu vejo problema. Apenas vejo espaço para melhoria, tanto para aumentar a visibilidade da pergunta quanto para futuras leitores que tenham a mesma dúvida. Mas OK. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu criava um dicionario com letra e valor tipo dict = {'A':1,'B':2} depois iterava pelas suas frutas sumando valores encontrados no dict.

Ps. Gostava de ver isto com list comprehensions ou algo mais simplificador do codigo (itertools por exemplo) ou algo parecido. Se algum coder mais avançado estiver por aí aceite o desafio :-)

ps . atençao se suas frutas sao maiusculas ou minusculas , vai variar. Veja o caso do B e b.

```
burakonta = {'a':1,'A':1, 'b':1,'B':2, 'e':1}
salada = ['uva','laranja','pera','BANANA','bananinha']

def qual_fruta():
    for fruta in salada:
        buracos(fruta)

def buracos(fruta, buracos=0):
    for letra in fruta:
        if letra in burakonta:
            buracos = buracos + burakonta[letra]
    print 'fruta %s tem %s buracos' %(fruta, buracos)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    qual_fruta()
```

resultado:

```
fruta uva tem 1 buracos
fruta laranja tem 3 buracos
fruta pera tem 2 buracos
fruta BANANA tem 5 buracos
fruta bananinha tem 4 buracos
```

Comment: O código deve ser escrito para receber apenas palavras inteiramente maiúsculas, mas obrigado por ter chamado a atenção. Quanto a lista de palavras, ela deve ser fornecida pelo usuário, e não por quem escreveu o código, por isso preciso usar raw_input de forma que o programa receba quantas entradas o usuário quiser fornecer. Irei me basear na sua resposta e procurar a solução. Grato!